# Vue.js Uso de v-model con componentes personalizados

Tags: vue.js

tengo un componente personalziado desarrollado con Vue.js. El componente es un wrapper que puede crear otro componente de manera dinámica dados unos parámetros por parámetro.

El problema lo tengo a la hora de usar el v-model de ese componente dinámico y vincularlo al modelo de la vista padre, el valor no se envía.

**Vista padre**

```
<component-wrapper v-model="wrapperValue" v-bind:childElement="{
    elementTag: 'b-form-input',
    childProps: {
      attrs: {
        id: 'foo'
      },
    }
}"/>
<p style="clear:both;">Wrapper value: {{wrapperValue}}</p>
```

**component-wrapper.js**

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.component('component-wrapper', {
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement(this.childElement.elementTag, this.childElement.childProps);
  },
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
  },
  props: {
    childElement: Object,
  },
  methods: {

  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Debes emitir el nuevo valor al padre con: `this.$emit('input', value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para modificar la propiedad que se pasa a través de v-model debes emitir un evento al componente padre haciendo uso del método **`$emit(event, value)`**.

Ten en cuenta que **`v-model="variable"`** no es más que una [forma abreviada de expresar](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components):

```
v-bind:value="variable"
v-on:input="variable = $event.target.value"
```

Como ves, el componente padre espera que el componente hijo emita un evento **input**
(Por defecto) y bindea al componente hijo la propiedad **value** (Por defecto),  su propiedad **variable**.

Si deseas que el nombre del evento o la propiedad bindeada al hijo sean distintas a las que vienen por defecto, pero seguir pudiendo utilizar **v-model**, debes declarar el nombre de éstas en la propiedad [**model**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model) del componente hijo:

```
model: {
  prop: 'checked',
  event: 'change'
}, ...
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo, como puedes ver podemos modificar el valor de la porpiedad desde el componente padre sin problemas, pero para la comunicación del hijo al padre se debe lanzar un evento:

```js
const Child = Vue.component('child', {
  created() {
    setInterval(this.emitRandomValue, 1000);
  },
  
  methods: {
    emitRandomValue() {
      const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      this.$emit('input', value);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    number: 0
  },
  
  components: {
    Child
  },
  
  created() {
    setInterval(() => this.number = '^', 500);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ number }}</p>
  <child v-model="number"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, he conseguido hacer que funcione.