# Como pasarle v-model a un componente custom

Tags: nuxt, vue2

Tengo el siguiente componente hijo que tiene 3 botones, y el apretar cada uno genera un contenido diferente. Estos contenidos pueden ser ordenados (draggable), eliminados y se pueden generar multiples de ellos. Todo se guarda en el array `this.contenido`.

Funciona perfectamente pero yo quiero hacer uso de este componente dentro de otros componentes y no sé como hacerlo.

Estoy viendo esta pregunta [Vue.js Uso de v-model con componentes personalizados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287158/vue-js-uso-de-v-model-con-componentes-personalizados) pero no estoy seguro de cómo emitir el evento "input" si estoy dentro de un gran componente `draggable`

Lo que yo deseo hacer es, llamar a este componente hijo desde un componente padre, pasandole por medio de `v-model` una variable, la cual sea modificada al mismo tiempo que en el componente hijo se modifica `this.contenido`

```
<template>
  <div class="container crear-contenido card pt-2 pb-4">
    <h2 class="text-center">Generar contenido</h2>
    <div class="d-flex m-auto pb-4">
      <base-button outline type="primary" @click="crearEditor">
        <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
        <span class="btn-inner--text">Editor WYSIWYG</span>
      </base-button>

      <base-button outline type="primary" @click="crearGaleria">
        <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
        <span class="btn-inner--text">Galeria</span>
      </base-button>

      <base-button outline type="primary" @click="crearVideo">
        <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></span>
        <span class="btn-inner--text">Video</span>
      </base-button>
    </div>

    <draggable
      :list="contenido"
      :disabled="!enabled"
      class="list-group"
      ghost-class="ghost"
      @start="dragging = true"
      @end="dragging = false"
    >
      <div v-for="(item, index) in contenido" :key="index">
        <div v-if="item.tipo == 'galeria'" class="container card pt-2 pb-4">
          ... una galeria de imagenes
        </div>

        <div v-else-if="item.tipo == 'video'" class="container card pt-2 pb-4">
         ... para cargar video ...
        </div>

        <div v-else-if="item.tipo == 'editor'" class="container card pt-2 pb-4">
          ...contenido wysiwyg...
        </div>
      </div>
    </draggable>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
export default {
  components: {
    draggable,
    "ckeditor-nuxt": () => {
      if (process.client) {
        return import("@blowstack/ckeditor-nuxt");
      }
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      enabled: true,
      contenido: [],
      editorConfig: {
        removePlugins: ["MediaEmbedToolbar", "Title"],
        simpleUpload: {
          uploadUrl: "path_to_image_controller",
          headers: {
            Authorization: "optional_token",
          },
        },
        wordCount: true,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    crearEditor() {
      let editor = {
        tipo: "editor",
        contenido: "",
      };
      this.contenido.push(editor);
    },
    crearGaleria() {
      let galeria = {
        tipo: "galeria",
        imagenes: [],
      };
      this.contenido.push(galeria);
    },
    crearVideo() {
      let video = {
        tipo: "video",
        url: "",
        comentario: "",
      };
      this.contenido.push(video);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finalmente lo solucioné con `$emit` y `custom events`. No sé si es la forma más óptima pero funcionó. Acepto cualquier corrección o sugerencia.

Declaré el siguiente método en `CrearContenido.vue`

```
emitEvent() {
  this.$emit('edit',this.contenido)
}
```

También declaré un `watcher` que se activa cuando el array `contenido` de `crearContenido.vue` es modificado

```
watch: {
 contenido() {
   this.emitEvent()
 },
},
```

Por ultimo, en el componente padre, cuando llamo a `CrearContenido`:

```
<crear-contenido @edit="changeExtraContent($event)" />
```

Y la declaración del método `changeExtraContent`

```
changeExtraContent(event){
  this.noticia.contenidoExtra = event
},
```